# Loop a FormControl in Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I am trying to loop through a nested form control in Angular using reactive forms.
There is a "taskSchedule" which has many "note" API data that needs to be looped through.

```
  this.profileForm = new FormGroup({
  userName: new FormControl(this.currentUserData.id),
  title: new FormControl(this.taskScheduleData.title),
  startDate: new FormControl(this.startDateConvert),
  endDate: new FormControl(this.endDateConvert),


  // this is where it should loop through the notes nested api data but it does not

  this.taskScheduleData.forEach(element => {
    this.notesForm = new FormGroup({
      notesInfo: new FormControl(this.taskScheduleData.notes[element].notesInfo),
     });
   });
});
```

API data

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "title": "Post test with notes",
    "start": "2020-09-14T12:00:00",
    "end": "2020-09-14T17:30:00",
    "userId": 2,
    "notes": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "notesInfo": "This is third notes",
            "dateCreated": "2020-09-14T12:12:00",
            "userId": 2,
            "taskScheduleId": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "notesInfo": "this is second notes",
            "dateCreated": "2020-09-20T22:43:00",
            "userId": 3,
            "taskScheduleId": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "notesInfo": "this is third notes",
            "dateCreated": "2020-09-20T22:43:00",
            "userId": 3,
            "taskScheduleId": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

There is an error that says

> Shadowed name: 'element' (no-shadowed-variable)

Clearly the foreach loop that I have coded is incorrect. Is there a way to loop through the 3 nested "notes" API data so that each note element has its own control form?

Comment: It is a linter error. Please show the full function code.

Comment: is `this.taskScheduleData` the notes array or the actual response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are looking for FormArray, not formGroup. If only want mannage the notesInfo, you create a formArray of FormControls

```
getFormGroup(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || {userName:null,title:null,startDate:null,endDate:null,notes:null}
   return new FormGroup({
     userName: new FormControl(data.userName),
     title: new FormControl(data.title),
     startDate: new FormControl(data.start?new Date(data.start):null),
     endDate: new FormControl(data.endDate?new Date(data.endDate):null),
     notes:new FormArray(data.notes?
         data.notes.map(x=>new FormControl(x.notesInfo):
         []
         )
   })
}
```

If you want to mannage notesInfo and anohters you create a formArray of FormGroups

```
getFormGroup(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || {userName:null,title:null,startDate:null,endDate:null,notes:null}
   return new FormGroup({
     userName: new FormControl(data.userName),
     title: new FormControl(data.title),
     startDate: new FormControl(data.start?new Date(data.start):null),
     endDate: new FormControl(data.endDate?new Date(data.endDate):null),
     notes:new FormArray(data.notes?
         data.notes.map(x=>this.getGroupNotes(x)):
         [])
   })
}

getGroupNotes(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || {id:nul,notesInfo:null,dateCreated:null,userId:null,taskSheduleId:null}
   return new FormGroup({
        id: new FormControl(data.id),
        notesInfo: new FormControl(data.notesInfo),
        dateCreated: new FormControl(data.dateCreated?new Date(data.dateCreated):null),
        userId: new FormControl(data.userId)
        taskScheduleId: new FormControl(data.taskScheduleId)
   })
}
```

then you can use as

```
  this.profileForm=this.getFromGroup(data) // create a FormGroup with data
  //or 
  this.profileForm=this.getFromGroup() // create a FormGroup empty
```

Comment: If I wanted to update a particular note which had id of 3, How would i update only that note and note all the notes in that array?

Comment: you can use setValue or patchValue. You need "reach" the formGroup or the formArray, some like `this.profileForm.get('notes') as FormArray).at(0).patchValue({notesInfo:'new note'})`, e.g. only change the value of the property notesInfo of the first element of the array